# Retrieve URL components using bash

Tags: string, bash, split, wget

I have a massive list of URLs in a text file, which I'd like to download using `wget`. This seems simple enough:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat list.txt | \
while read CMD; do

  wget $CMD; done;
```

However, wget uses the basename of the file as the download location, which results in renaming schemes, such as `file.txt.1`, `file.txt.2` and so on.

An `$URL` can look like this:

```
http://sub.domain.com/some/folder/to/file.txt
```

Where `http://sub.domain.com/some/` is always the same. Now, in JS I would do `$URL.split("http://sub.domain.com/some/")[1]`, but this doesn't quite seem to work in Bash:

```
IFS="http://sub.domain.com/some/" read -a url <<< "http://sub.domain.com/some/folder/to/file.txt"

echo "${url[1]}"; // always empty.
```

Comment: What about awk? `awk -v FS="http://sub.domain.com/some/" '{print $1}'` . or use sed and replace the delimiter with empty string.

Comment: What about using [`wget -x $CMD`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory-Options) to force directory generation on save?

Answer (score 2):

Use the shell's [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) operator to remove the prefix:

```
base=${CMD#http://sub.domain.com/some/}
```

BTW, you should get out of the habit of using all-uppercase variable names in shell scripts. These are conventionally used for environment variables.

Comment: I gave a link to the documentation, it should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the prefix is static you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    suffix=${line:${#line} - LENGTH}
    wget $line -O $suffix
done < "list.txt"
```